# Why doesn't this pass the borrow checker?

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust, reference, borrow-checker, borrowing

I'm trying to solve the Spiral Order question on leetcode by splitting off the top and bottom rows one by one, and I ran into a problem with the borrow checker that I can't make sense of. This is the minimal example that creates the compile error:

```rust
pub fn f(mut matrix: &mut [Vec<i32>]) {
    while let Some((_, remainder)) = matrix.split_first_mut() {
        matrix = remainder;
        if let Some((_, remainder)) = matrix.split_first_mut() {
            matrix = remainder;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my full code, for context of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```rust
impl Solution {
    pub fn spiral_order(mut matrix: Vec<Vec<i32>>) -> Vec<i32> {
        let mut matrix = &mut matrix[..];
        if matrix.is_empty() {
            return Vec::new();
        }
        let mut ans = Vec::with_capacity(matrix.len() * matrix[0].len());
        while let Some((head, tail)) = matrix.split_first_mut() {
            ans.append(head);
            matrix = tail;
            for row in matrix.iter_mut() {
                ans.push(row.pop().unwrap());
            }
            if let Some((head, tail)) = matrix.split_last_mut() {
                matrix = tail;
                ans.extend(head.into_iter().rev().map(|&mut x| x));
            }
        }
        ans
    }
}
```

It seems to think that the inner borrow conflicts with the subsequent outer borrow in the next iteration of the loop, but I think it should be okay because I move the remainder back into matrix, so there is a valid `&mut [Vec<i32>]` in there before the iteration ends. Why is this failing to compile, and how should it be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why your original version doesn't compile but I don't think `split_first_mut` and `split_last_mut` are the tools for the job. I was to simplify the implementation and make it compile by switching to `remove` and `pop` instead:

```rust
fn spiral_order(mut matrix: Vec<Vec<i32>>) -> Vec<i32> {
    if matrix.is_empty() {
        return Vec::new();
    }
    let mut ans = Vec::with_capacity(matrix.len() * matrix[0].len());
    while !matrix.is_empty() {
        let mut head = matrix.remove(0);
        ans.append(&mut head);
        for row in matrix.iter_mut() {
            ans.push(row.pop().unwrap());
        }
        if let Some(head) = matrix.pop() {
            ans.extend(head.into_iter().rev());
        }
    }
    ans
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1e1ae8e4fa7061a9717c61bad995ff1d)

---

More optimal solution, without any `matrix` mutations or copies:

```rust
fn spiral_order(matrix: Vec<Vec<i32>>) -> Vec<i32> {
    if matrix.len() == 0 || matrix[0].len() == 0 {
        return Vec::new();
    }

    let mut row = 0;
    let mut col = 0;
    let mut up = 0;
    let mut down = matrix.len() as i32 - 1;
    let mut left = 0;
    let mut right = matrix[0].len() as i32 - 1;
    let mut dir = (0, 1);
    let mut ans = Vec::with_capacity(matrix.len() * matrix[0].len());

    for _ in 0..(matrix.len() * matrix[0].len()) {
        ans.push(matrix[row as usize][col as usize]);

        match dir {
            (0, 1) if col == right => {
                dir = (1, 0);
                up += 1;
            }
            (1, 0) if row == down => {
                dir = (0, -1);
                right -= 1;
            }
            (0, -1) if col == left => {
                dir = (-1, 0);
                down -= 1;
            }
            (-1, 0) if row == up => {
                dir = (0, 1);
                left += 1;
            }
            _ => (),
        }

        row += dir.0;
        col += dir.1;
    }

    ans
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e34d6333d9e13ed59049f18e39ddd276)

Comment: I did first consider using `remove` and `pop`, but the problem is that `remove` has the wrong time complexity, and I wasn't happy with that when I'm practicing implementing algorithms. I was also considering converting to a VecDeque to get O(1) removals from the front, but that might reallocate, which gives the wrong space complexity. That's why I was using slices.

Comment: @LionelFoxcroft if you're concerned about the time complexity of methods which mutation `matrix` then don't mutate it, and if you are concerned about the space complexity of copying `matrix` then don't copy it. This problem doesn't require either of those 2 things. I've updated my answer with a more optimal solution.

Comment: I actually already implemented a solution like what you just posted, I wanted to retry it by doing the slice/pop thing to possibly take advantage of the speed of copying the upper part of the spiral as one long chunk, as well as just to try representing the algorithm another way. I was really just confused about the borrow checker thing, but I upvoted your answer because it's a good solution and I appreciate the effort.